# Convert CGPoint from CGRect to other CGRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect, cgpoint

I have placed one label on view and view's frame is **CGRectMake(0,0,270,203)**. Now I have to take screen shot of view with **CGRectMake(0,0,800,600)**. So I have to **convert label from old rect to new rect**.

here is code which I used to take screen shot:

```
CGRect rect = [view bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Here is the code which I used to convert point:

```
CGRect f = [view convertRect:lblMessage.frame fromView:viewMessage];
```

But I am not able to get actual position from label in new image. Can anyone help where I am wrong.

Here I have attached image for more clarification. 
In small view, I have add one label and I have to convert label's frame as per big image view.

[image: Convert label from this view to big view.]

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Is your label actually inside the `view`? Please add some details about the view hierarchy. Please, specify where you expect the label to be on the resulting image.

Answer (score 0):

```
    +(UIImage*)screenShotOf:(UIView*)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, scale);
        [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return img;
    }
```

**Here You need to adjust the scale property as you needed.**

Comment: I have used your code. But label is not same frame as its in small view.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
-(CGPoint) convertPoint: (CGPoint) point fromRect: (CGRect) fromRect toRect: (CGRect) toRect {
    return (CGPoint){
        (toRect.size.width/fromRect.size.width) * point.x,
        (toRect.size.height/fromRect.size.height) * point.y
    };
}
```