# iPad Size and Coordinates scale to iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm working on this objective c game app where the screen is populated with pictures of animals.

The problem is that the size and x/y of the animal is hard coded in the app and works with the iPad Air screen dimensions. My question is how can I scale it to show up in the same position and size on an iPhone 7 plus? Is there a formula to scale the size and x/y coordinates?

I looked for answers on stackoverflow with an answer saying to divide the dimensions but when i tried that the x/y coordinates were off.

Here is the code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
   NSString *sonidoPathBell1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bellTransition" ofType:@"aif"];
   NSURL *sonidoUrlBell1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:sonidoPathBell1];
   AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)sonidoUrlBell1, &sonTrans);

   btnAnimales = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
   for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    OBShapedButton *tempbtn = [[OBShapedButton alloc] init];
    [tempbtn setTag:i+1];
    opcion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bluebaymobAmazingMixAndMatchObjeto%i",i + 1]];
    if (opcion == 0) {
        [tempbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"btnAni%i.png",i+1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        [tempbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"btnAni%iColor.png",i+1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [tempbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(startPuzzle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    CGRect cuadro = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    switch(i+1){
        case 1:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(131, 85, 95, 120);
            //cuadro = CGRectMake(94, 48, 65, 60);
            //37, 37, 30, 60
            break;
        case 2:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(52, 246, 147, 157);
            //cuadro = CGRectMake(15, 209, 117, 97);
            break;
        case 3:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(-5, 418, 166, 158);

            break;
        case 4:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(301, 64, 156, 151);

            break;
        case 5:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(214, 213, 129, 190);
            break;
        case 6:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(165, 384, 162, 169);
            break;
        case 7:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(204, 615, 139, 153);
            break;
        case 8:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(458, 115, 109, 90);
            break;
        case 9:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(367, 222, 207, 130);
            break;
        case 10:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(361, 344, 408, 276);
            break;
        case 11:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(387, 591, 234, 173);
            break;
        case 12:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(605, 104, 92, 131);
            break;
        case 13:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(671, 220, 152, 155);
            break;
        case 14:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(760, 450, 137, 174);
            break;
        case 15:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(701, 613, 101, 161);
            break;
        case 16:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(660, 26, 132, 88);
            break;
        case 17:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(828, 36, 112, 107);
            break;
        case 18:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(820, 288, 153, 157);
            break;
        case 19:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(909, 441, 115, 162);
            break;
        case 20:
            cuadro = CGRectMake(862, 629, 151, 135);
            break;
    }

    //1920 x1080 iphone 7plus
    //2048 x 1536 ipad
    //.9375
    //cuadro.origin.x = cuadro.origin.x * .9375;
    //cuadro.origin.y = cuadro.origin.y * .703125;
    //cuadro.origin.x = cuadro.origin.x - 37;
    //cuadro.origin.y = cuadro.origin.y - 37;
    //cuadro.size.width = cuadro.size.width - 30;
    //cuadro.size.height = cuadro.size.height - 60;
    tempbtn.frame = cuadro;
    [btnAnimales addObject:tempbtn];
    [self.view addSubview:[btnAnimales objectAtIndex:i]];
    tempbtn = nil;
}
```

}

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Edited my answer to show the code.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any logic behind these sizes and location of images. All the buttons are manually sized and positions.  And from the looks of it, It looks like you are creating a grid type design. So the best approach for you would be to use UICollectionView, which will take care of the size and all.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24213442/934710