# How to position the CALayer in a video?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have a UIView (**size: W: 375 H: 667**) with an image that can be placed anywhere inside it. Later this image will be overlaid with a video and saved. My problem is when I view the video the image is not found on the same position chosen in my UIView because my video is at a size of **(720 x 1280)**. How can I reflect the position of the chosen image in my UIView inside a Video **(720 x 1280**)?
This is the code I'm using:

```
private func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset,modelView:MyViewModel, watermarkText text : String!, imageName name : String!, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSession.Status?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {

         DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {

            let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()


            let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
            let clipVideoTrack:AVAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
            do {
                try compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: videoAsset.duration), of: clipVideoTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }


            let videoSize = self.resolutionSizeForLocalVideo(asset: clipVideoTrack)
              print("DIMENSIONE DEL VIDEO W: \(videoSize.width) H: \(videoSize.height)")

            let parentLayer = CALayer()
            let videoLayer = CALayer()

            parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
            videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)


            parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

             //My layer image
            let layerTest = CALayer()

            layerTest.frame = modelView.frame
            layerTest.contents = modelView.image.cgImage

            print("A: \(modelView.frame.origin.y)    -     \(modelView.frame.origin.x)")
            print("B: \(layerTest.frame.origin.y)     -     \(layerTest.frame.origin.x)")
            parentLayer.addSublayer(layerTest)

           print("PARENT: \(parentLayer.frame.origin.y)    -     \(parentLayer.frame.origin.x)")
            //------------------------

            let videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
            videoComp.renderSize = videoSize
            videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
            videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)

            let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

            instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: mixComposition.duration)

              let layerInstruction = self.videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: compositionVideoTrack!, asset: videoAsset)
            layerInstruction.setTransform((clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform), at: CMTime.zero)

            instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
            videoComp.instructions = [instruction]

            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            let date = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory).appendingPathComponent("watermarkVideo-\(date).mp4")

            let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
            exporter?.outputURL = url
            exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
            exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
            exporter?.videoComposition = videoComp

            exporter?.exportAsynchronously() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if exporter?.status == AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed {
                        let outputURL = exporter?.outputURL
                        if flag {
                            // Save to library
                            //                            let library = ALAssetsLibrary()

                            if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL!.path) {
                                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputURL!)
                                }) { saved, error in
                                    if saved {
                                        completion!(AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed, exporter, outputURL)
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            //                            if library.videoAtPathIs(compatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum: outputURL) {
                            //                                library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL,
                            //                                                                           completionBlock: { (assetURL:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                            //
                            //                                                                            completion!(AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed, exporter, outputURL)
                            //                                })
                            //                            }
                        } else {
                            completion!(AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed, exporter, outputURL)
                        }

                    } else {
                        // Error
                        completion!(exporter?.status, exporter, nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }


    private func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {


        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
        let scale : CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y:1)
        instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scale), at: CMTime.zero)
        return instruction
    }
```

This is what I would like to get:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465725/convert-cgpoint-from-cgrect-to-other-cgrect) may be helpful. I faced a similar problem when attempting to position user-generated text over a video. This is what worked for me:

First, I added a helper method to convert a CGPoint from one rect to another:

```
func convertPoint(point: CGPoint, fromRect: CGRect, toRect: CGRect) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: (toRect.size.width / fromRect.size.width) * point.x, y: (toRect.size.height / fromRect.size.height) * point.y)
}
```

I positioned my text view (in your case, an image view) using its center point. Here's how you could calculate an adjusted center point using the helper method:

```
let adjustedCenter = convertPoint(point: imageView.center, fromRect: view.frame, toRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 720.0, height: 1280.0))
```

I had to do some extra positioning after that because the coordinate system for CALayers is flipped, so this is what the final point might look like:

```
let finalCenter = CGPoint(x: adjustedCenter.x, y: (1280.0 - adjustedCenter.y) - (imageView.bounds.height / 2.0))
```

Then you would set your CALayer's position property to that point.

```
layerTest.position = finalCenter
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Does your code always place the image in the center of the video (760 x 1280)? because from the tests that I am carrying out with your code wherever I place the image inside my UVIEW, the image is always centered within the video, not respecting the position I have chosen within the UIView.